# single query which can return a Message, To Name and From Name

Tags: mysql

```
Table_Users
id  username
1   Jack
2   Marine
3   Katie
4   Hennry

Table_Messages
id  to_id   from_id Messages
1   2   3   Hello
2   3   2   Hi
```

**Need a single query which can return a Message, To Name and From Name**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the table `users` on table `messages` twice since you need to get the equivalent names for `to` and`from` users.

```
SELECT  a.id,
        b.`username` TO_NAME,
        c.`username`  FROM_NAME,
        a.Messages
FROM    tbl_Messages a
        INNER JOIN users b
            on a.to_ID  = b.id
        INNER JOIN users c
            on a.from_ID = c.id
```

## [See SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2eadc/1)

Comment: Great, i tried it and is working fine but Is this the best way to do it or there can be different syntax also ?

Comment: so far,I can say that this is the most efficient solution. There are other solutions where in you can get values from the subquery which is less efficient than this. :D

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers. :D

Comment: can you explain me how do you decided to use INNER join why not Left/Right Join

Comment: @Vikki because I assumed that in every record, there is a `to_id` and `from_id`. If any of them did not exist, the whole record won't show because `INNER JOIN` will only display records that returns true on the condition supplied in `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query :

select messages as Message, (select users from table_users where id=to_id) as "From Name", (select users from table_users where id=from_id) as "To Name" from table_messages;

Comment: wow here is another way which also results the same result as explained above.